# Finding average area of a column in a csv files with some twist

Tags: python, csv, iteration, multiple-columns, area

I am trying to create a function that returns the average area of a column in a csv file ('land_info.csv', 'farm_area'). I'm having trouble with this for a few reasons:

My biggest problem is that the column name has weird characters in it so I'm trying to call it with an index? (I'm not sure if I worded that right). I'm not allowed to import any other files (like pandas), except for the main one (land_info.csv). The areas in the column are strings, but I'm trying to return the value as a float. Some of the farms also don't have an area, so the string is empty - and I'm not sure how to treat that as 0.

Here's what part of the column looks like, but the actual file is pretty big.

| farm_area |
| --- |
| 92.82 |
| 66.7 |
| #empty |
| 1.2 |
| 1164 |
| 21.4 |
| 11.3 |
| #empty |
| 11 |

Because I'm trying  to return this value to be printed later somewhere else, I've been using this basic outline and then trying different functions:

```
import csv

def get_av_area(filename, column_name):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)



    return
```

But so far everything I've been trying hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import csv

with open("yourfile location here", "r") as farming_areas:
    file_read = csv.reader(farming_areas)
    listoflists = list(file_read)
#all values separated into list of lists
print(listoflists)

print(np.matrix(listoflists))

listoflists[0] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[0]]
listoflists[1] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[1]]
listoflists[2] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[2]]
listoflists[3] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[3]]
listoflists[4] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[4]]
listoflists[5] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[5]]
listoflists[6] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[6]]
listoflists[7] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[7]]
listoflists[8] = [0 if i=='' else i for i in listoflists[8]]

print(listoflists[0])
```

Try this. This will make all of your empty columns 0's. You this should have the values able to be stored for later as a list as well. I am assuming this is a 8 by 8 in your csv. You will have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: It will also keep your values that are already there the same too.

Comment: You can use it as a matrix too if you want to do np.matrix(listoflists)